# Prolog syntax error: . or operator expected after expression 1 error(s) compilation failed

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve the problem of cryptarithmetic puzzle by using Prolog, and the question is

```
  TWO 
 +TWO
——————
 FOUR
```

Here is my code, could anyone please help me with that question?

```
solution (T, W, O, F, U, R) :-
    select(T, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], L1),
    select(W, L1, L2),
    select(O, L2, L3),
    select(F, L3, L4),
    select(U, L4, L5),
    member(R,L5),
    
    FOUR is F * 1000 + O * 100 + U * 10 + R,
    TWO is T * 100 + W * 10 + O,
    FOUR is TWO + TWO.
```

Comment: On the second last line you have a lower case "o" instead of upper case "O". You could also maybe write `F * 1000 + O * 100 + U * 10 + R =:= 2 * (T * 100 + W * 10 + O)`

Comment: what do you mean by `member(R,15)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program logic seems right.

Just a syntax error: you cannot put a space between the procedure name and the `(`. So the head of your procedure should be `solution(T, W, O, F, U, R) :-`.

Maybe you want to avoid `F` being `0`. In that case modify the constraints(and maybe rearrange the letter assignments). You may also add parameters TWO and FOUR:

```
solution(T, W, O, F, U, R, TWO, FOUR) :-
    select(F, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], L1),  % F cannot be 0
    select(T, [0|L1], L2), 
    select(W, L2, L3),
    select(O, L3, L4),
    select(U, L4, L5),
    member(R,L5),

    FOUR is F * 1000 + O * 100 + U * 10 + R,
    TWO is T * 100 + W * 10 + O,
    FOUR is TWO + TWO.
```

Printing all solutions:

```
?- solution(T, W, O, F, U, R, TWO, FOUR), writeln(TWO + TWO = FOUR),fail.
734+734=1468
765+765=1530
836+836=1672
846+846=1692
867+867=1734
928+928=1856
938+938=1876
false.
```